# NumPy dot product of matrix and array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

From numpy's documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot

> numpy.dot(a, b, out=None)
>
> Dot product of two arrays. Specifically,
>
> - If both a and b are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation).
> - If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using matmul or a @ b is preferred.
> - If either a or b is 0-D (scalar), it is equivalent to multiply and using numpy.multiply(a, b) or a * b is preferred.
> - If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and b.
> - If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b:

According to the 4th point, if we take the dot product of a 2-D array A and a 1-D array B, we should be taking the sum product over the columns of A and row of B since the last axis of A is the column, correct?
Yet, when I tried this in the Python IDLE, here is my output:

```
>>> a
    array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4],
           [5, 6]])
>>> b
    [1, 2]
>>> a.dot(b)
    array([ 5, 11, 17])
```

I expected this to throw an error since the dimension of a's columns is greater than the dimension of b's row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and b.

The last axis of `a` has size 2:

```
>>> a.shape
(3, 2)
```

which matches `b`s size.

Remember: the first axis for multi-dimensional arrays in numpy is 'downward'. 1D arrays are displayed horizontally in numpy but I think it's usually better to think of them as vertical vectors instead. This is what's being computed:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. But, does this mean row vectors are the "last axis" of a matrix? I was confused by the terminology of the documentation. I figured sum product over the last axis must be column vectors since columns are the last axis.

Comment: @user3882 Columns are not the last axis.

Comment: The docs don't use 'columns' or 'rows'.  Those names are ok for 2d arrays, but must be used with caution when the array is 1d. `b` shape is (2,) - that's the one and only dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj I know, I never claimed otherwise. I say that 1D arrays are *displayed* horizontally, but I often *think of them* as vertical vectors (especially in the context of linear algebra), not that they intrinsically are either of those. They are of course one-dimensional.

Comment: My comment was intended for the OP who I presume is notified of all comments.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the clarification. So when arrays have shape (n, 1), does this mean that the array is actually 2 dimensional?

Comment: Yes, the shape tuple has 2 elements.  (1,n) is also 2d.  For these the 2nd point applies.